# How to add a member and task allocated if not found in dynamically populated dropdownlst

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have reviewed suggested solutions but did not find any matching my issue.

We have a SELECT list that is dynamically populated from the database.

Each time a staff wishes to create a task and allocate time to complete the task, s/he selects the member who would handle that task and then allocates time to complete the task. This works fine.

```
//JS

    function populateMember() {

        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url: 'php/getMember.php?mode=edited&rowId=' + $.urlParam('id'), // the url where we want to POST
                dataType: 'html', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                encode: true
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
                var newRows = (returnedData.length - 3);
                if (returnedData.length > 3){
                    var x = 0;
                    for (x=0; x < newRows; x++){
                        $( "#newMember" ).trigger( "click" );
                    }
                }
                var i=0;
                for (i in returnedData){
                    $('#member' + i).val(returnedData[i][0]);
                    $('#task_time_alocatted' + i).val(returnedData[i][1]);
                }

            })
            .error(function () {});
    }
    
    //PHP
<?php
//Connect to server
///Connection info goes here
}

//These are parameters from the POST request
$mode = $_GET[ 'mode' ];
$rowId = (int) $_GET[ 'rowId' ];

$sql = "SELECT member, task_time_allocated FROM TaskAllocations WHERE parent_task_id = $rowId;";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if ( $stmt === false ) {
    $theErrors = sqlsrv_errors();
    array_push($messages, 0, $sql, $theErrors);
    echo json_encode($messages);
    die();
} else {
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH) ) {
          array_push($messages, [$row['member'], $row['task_time_allocated']]);
    }
    echo json_encode($messages);
}

?>
```

However, if the member that a staff is trying to select from the SELECT list is not on that list, we would like two text boxes, one for the member and one for task to be allocated to that member.

How do we handle this?

We have created this on the HTML form:

```
//JS
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnstaff").click(function () {
              if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == "amend") {
                  $.each($('.dvstaff'), function(i, item){
                  $(this).show();
                });
                $(this).val("Cancel");
            } else {
                  $.each($('.dvstaff'), function(i, item){
                  $(this).hide();
                });
                $(this).val("Amend");
            }
          });

        });
    </script>


   //HTML
   <input id="btnstaff" type="button" value="Amend" name="btnstaff" />
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><div class="dvstaff" style="display: none"><input id="amendmember" class="shortText" style="width:242px;" name="amendmember"></div></td>
       <td>
         <div class="dvstaff" style="display: none"><input id="amendtime" class="shortText" placeholder="0" name="amendtime">&nbsp;%</div></td>
     </tr>
```

You click Amend and it creates two blank textboxes, one for new member and the other for task_time_allocated.

We would prefer to handle this Amend bit on the JS that invokes the getMember method since the HTML is generated from the JS.

Is this possible?

Comment: HI, can you elaborate more ? Your amend part hide/show is working so what you need to do ?

Comment: Yes, the Amend part is working when added to the HTML page where you have to click the Amend button to show the textboxes.

Our preference is to integrate with the JS function -> function populateMember() {...}
in such that if the member the staff wishes to select is not on the SELECT list, then an option that says something like Add new member. So that a staff would click that option to show two boxes, one to add member and the other to add task_time_allocated. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: You can just add one extra row when you append new `newMember` i.e : after this `for (i in returnData){}` add one extra row with your button and that two inptus then append that as well inside your table .

Comment: @Swati, I do not understand your suggested solution. Both codes are there. Do you mind showing me?

Comment: Hi, you can do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nw48frdu/) .

Comment: @Swati, thank you so much for your assistance. I have not tested this solution yet because they decided to abandon the approach but I still think it was an awesome solution from. I will eventually test it and let you know if it worked. In the meanwhile, an upvote for you for a creative solution.